Overlapping and Non overlappping SQL query
We have below schema:
CREATE TABLE enrollments (
    case_id INT,
    enrollment_id VARCHAR(10),
    open_date DATE,
    closed_date DATE,
    status VARCHAR(10)
);

Let's assume the records are:
INSERT INTO enrollments (case_id, enrollment_id, open_date, closed_date, status)
VALUES
(1, 'ab', '2024-10-01', '2024-10-05', 'closed'),
(1, 'bc', '2024-10-03', '2024-10-04', 'closed'),
(1, 'bd', '2024-10-05', '2024-10-15', 'closed'),
(1, 'sx', '2024-10-12', '2024-10-19', 'closed'),
(1, 'za', '2024-10-16', '2024-10-21', 'closed'),
(1, 'ca', '2024-10-25', '2024-10-26', 'closed'),
(1, 'dd', '2024-10-25', '2024-10-27', 'closed'),
(1, 'kh', '2024-10-28', NULL, 'open'),
(1, 'kk', '2024-10-28', NULL, 'open');

I want only the records

Consider only the cpe's which are not overlapping with previous enrollments, i.e. the open date of current enrollment should not fall between open and closed date of previous enrollment.

If two enrollments are started on same open date consider the long lasting enrollemnt, i.e. latest closed_date.

If we have two open enrollments which open dates are not overlapping consider both of them.

Validate the current enrollment only with previous valid enrollments which means the record 'za' enrollment is not overlapping with previous valid enrollment, then we need to consider this record even though it is overlapping with 'sx' record becuase 'sx' is an invalid cpe as it overlapped.


So I need this output:



case_id
enrollment_id
open_date
closed_date
status




1
ab
01-10-2024
05-10-2024
closed


1
bd
05-10-2024
15-10-2024
closed


1
za
16-10-2024
21-10-2024
closed


1
dd
25-10-2024
27-10-2024
closed


1
kh
28-10-2024
NULL
open


1
kk
28-10-2024
NULL
open



How can I do this?

This will be a gaps and islands problem, so adding that tag.

Hey Ashok. This is a polite reminder that this is not a forum to do your work; it is a forum to assist you to do your work. Next time please provide what you have tried and what the outcome was. That way we can help you fix your errors instead of doing the work for you. Having said that, my compliments on the clarity of your question.

One option to do it is to create a cte (grid) that would flag different date anomalies as "Overlap", "Long", "Opened" or Null. In main sql use the flag column in Case expressions to define open_date column for the rows of interest or Null for those to be excluded.
Sample table enrollments



case_id
enrollment_id
open_date
closed_date
status




1
ab
2024-10-01
2024-10-05
closed


1
bc
2024-10-03
2024-10-04
closed


1
bd
2024-10-05
2024-10-15
closed


1
sx
2024-10-12
2024-10-19
closed


1
za
2024-10-16
2024-10-21
closed


1
ca
2024-10-25
2024-10-26
closed


1
dd
2024-10-25
2024-10-27
closed


1
kh
2024-10-28
null
open


1
kk
2024-10-28
null
open



--      flag different cases 
WITH
  grid AS
     ( Select  g.*, Case When ( g.open_date = g.prev_open Or g.open_date = g.next_open ) And g.status = 'closed'
                         Then 'Long'
                         When ( g.open_date = g.prev_open Or g.open_date = g.next_open )
                         Then 'Opened'
                         When g.open_date < g.prev_close 
                         Then 'Overlap' 
                    End as flag
       From   ( Select   e.*, 
                         LAG(e.open_date) Over(Partition By e.case_id Order By e.open_date) as prev_open,  
                         LAG(e.closed_date) Over(Partition By e.case_id Order By e.open_date) as prev_close,  
                         LEAD(e.open_date) Over(Partition By e.case_id Order By e.open_date) as next_open 
                From     enrollments e
                Order By e.case_id, e.open_date
              ) g
       Order By  g.case_id, g.open_date
     ) 

--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT x.*
FROM 
  ( Select    case_id, enrollment_id, 
              Case When flag Is Null 
                   Then open_date
                   When flag = 'Overlap' And 
                        open_date < Max(Case When flag Is Null Then closed_date End)
                                   Over(Partition By case_id Order By open_date 
                                        Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding)
                   Then Null
                   When flag = 'Overlap' And 
                        open_date > Max(Case When flag Is Null Then closed_date End)
                                   Over(Partition By case_id Order By open_date 
                                        Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding)
                   Then open_date
                   When flag = 'Long' And
                        open_date = next_open
                   Then Null
                   When flag = 'Long' And
                        open_date != next_open
                   Then open_date
              Else open_date
              End as new_open_date,
              closed_date, 
              status
    From      grid
    Order By  case_id, new_open_date
  ) x
WHERE x.new_open_date Is Not Null

R e s u l t :



case_id
enrollment_id
new_open_date
closed_date
status




1
ab
2024-10-01
2024-10-05
closed


1
bd
2024-10-05
2024-10-15
closed


1
za
2024-10-16
2024-10-21
closed


1
dd
2024-10-25
2024-10-27
closed


1
kh
2024-10-28
null
open


1
kk
2024-10-28
null
open



fiddle
